# jQuery AJAX url wit variable

Tags: ajax, jquery

For an AJAX call I try to get the url from a variable

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var url = 'test';
$.ajax({
    'url': url,
    'data': ({todo: "food-page_catfetch"}),
    'success': function(data) {
        $('.catspinner__food_page').fadeOut("fast", function(){
            $('#food_result__cats').html(data);
        });
    }
});
});
```

If I look in the inspector I see this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var url = 'test';
$.ajax({
    'url': url, 
    'data': ({todo: "food-page_catfetch"}),
    'success': function(data) {
        $('.catspinner__food_page').fadeOut("fast", function(){
            $('#food_result__cats').html(data);
        });
    }
});
});
```

And I want this

```
'url': test,
```

I tried different ways but I cant fixed this who can help me?

Comment: what you want and what you have are equivalent, `url` is a variable containing the string `'test'`. Whatever the problem is that you're trying to solve, this is a red herring, it already does what you are trying to make it do, it is not the source of your problem. But even if it was ( which it isn't ) you can just edit `url` to `test` in the code. Perhaps you need to explain things differently? If this question is pure javascript then you should ask it on stackoverflow

Comment: you may be thinking in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with Axios instead jQuery and check the response, example

```
let form_data = new FormData;
form_data.append('action', 'myAction');
form_data.append('first_name', 'my first name');

axios.post(myVars.ajax_url, form_data).then(function(response){
  console.log('response', response.data);
}).cath(console.log)
```